# Access to controls: Nested repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How can i get a textbox that it's located in another repeater ?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server">
         ....
       </asp:Repeater>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm in repeater2 ItemDataBound and i need to get the value of the TextBox1 , how can i do it .

```
 Protected Sub Repeater2_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)  

??

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NamingContainer` of the inner repeater is the `RepeaterItem` of the outer `Repeater`, then use `FindControl` to get the reference to the `TextBox`:

```
protected void Repeater2_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater innerRepeater = (Repeater) sender;
        RepeaterItem outerItem = (RepeaterItem) innerRepeater.NamingContainer;
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox) outerItem.FindControl("TextBox1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
Dim tb = DirectCast(sender, WebControl).NamingContainer.FindControl("TextBox1")
```